# How do I collect the data on a Vertex as I traverse a graph, and then output it along with the results?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am experimenting with using a graph database to model a simple newsfeed.  Although I am not using Neo4j, I am roughly following this model for my graph:

http://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html

The gremlin query below retrieves the 15 most recent posts from each of a users friends, as well as the users own posts. (I will rank, filter and paginate this later).

```
g.V().hasLabel("user").has("userid", "john.smith")
     .union(
         out("posted"),
         both("friend").out("posted")
     ).next(15).toList();
```

The problem is that I need to retrieve data about the `users` themselves. Things like avatar url, display name etc.  This data is stored as properties on each `user` vertex.

How can I collect this data as I traverse the graph and output it along with each post?

It would be great to simply be able to return each post with an injected `user` object, containing all the properties of the `user` vertex connected to each post:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use [select()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#select-step)

```
g.V().hasLabel("user").has("userid", "john.smith").as('user')
     .union(
         out("posted"),
         both("friend").out("posted")
     ).as('posts').select('user','posts').next(15).toList();
```

Comment: Perfect, i'm new to graph databases and your example has helped me grasp some fundamental concepts.  Cheers!